# Oracle SQL: Self join and self lookup

Tags: self-join

Need help. I am putting my requirement in simple steps here. I have a data like below.

```
with x as (
select 'a=x AND b=y AND c=z' C1, 'a' C2, '100' C3 from dual union all
select 'a=x AND b=y AND c=z' C1, 'b' C2, '200' C3 from dual union all
select 'a=x AND b=y AND c=z' C1, 'c' C2, '300' C3 from dual union all
select 'a=x AND d=y AND c=z' C1, 'd' C2, '400' C3 from dual union all
select 'a=x AND e=y AND c=z' C1, 'e' C2, '500' C3 from dual 
)
select * from x;
```

My output looks like below:

```
     C1              C2   C3
------------------------------
a=x AND b=y AND c=z   a 100
a=x AND b=y AND c=z   b 200
a=x AND b=y AND c=z   c 300
a=x AND d=y AND c=z   d 400
a=x AND e=y AND c=z   e 500
```

I am looking for a query to get the output like below. I have a condition in one column (C1), Also I have look-up data in same table in different columns (C2 and C3). I want to replace the values in C1 if any of the string exists in column C2 with the value from column C3.

```
100=x AND 200=y AND 300=z     a    100
100=x AND 200=y AND 300=z     b    200
100=x AND 200=y AND 300=z     c    300
100=x AND 400=y AND 300=z     d    400
100=x AND 500=y AND 300=z     e    500
```

My exact requirement is, I have a table with a column contains WHERE condition (C1) like above. They used business column names in condition and there is second column with business name (C2) and there is third column with actual physical column name in DB (C3) in the same table. I am looking for the query which can replace the business names in C1, by looking at column C2 with the corresponding value in column C3.

Comment: This appears to be a good candidate for "tell us the actual problem that you're trying to solve, rather than posting your broken solution and asking us to fix it."  See [What is the X Y Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I have updated the description. Could you please check if it makes sense ?